# i have 2 collections i want to compare and check if there is a difference in ANgular 4 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need your help, I have 2 collections (Old and new) and I want to compare and check if there is a change using Angular 4 Typescript can anyone help me or guide me on how to achieve this

Comment: use isEqual from lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

Comment: What is the collection? An array?

Comment: can you brief out a little. Collection mean? Are you referring to a list or Array?

Comment: yes the collection is like this 
[
Object1 { Prop1 = "Val", Pro2="Val"......}
Object2 { Prop1 = "Val", Pro2="Val"......}
Object3 { Prop1 = "Val", Pro2="Val"......}
]

i have 2 such lists and i need to compare if its changed 
and can i use ngonchanges ? to detect changes?